# Array random with no matching

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to do randomized country flags side by side, but I need it to not match with each other, but my case is more specific for the solutions I found about the arrays:

```
function flags() {
var flagurls = ["ZPlo8tpmp/chi","cJBo8tpk6/sov","QyLo8tpkm/rus","68so8tpl4/pol","x1Ro8tplj/nor","TT3o8tplv/lit","IsZo8tpma/isr"];
var randomize = 'url("http://static.tumblr.com/zicio7x/'+flagurls[Math.floor(Math.random()*flagurls.length)]+'.png")';
var randomize2 = 'url("http://static.tumblr.com/zicio7x/'+flagurls[Math.floor(Math.random()*flagurls.length)]+'.png")';
document.getElementById("th1").style.backgroundImage = randomize;
document.getElementById("th2").style.backgroundImage = randomize2;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `while` loop:

```
function flags () {
  var flagurls = ["ZPlo8tpmp/chi","cJBo8tpk6/sov","QyLo8tpkm/rus","68so8tpl4/pol","x1Ro8tplj/nor","TT3o8tplv/lit","IsZo8tpma/isr"];
  var randomize = 'url("http://static.tumblr.com/zicio7x/'+flagurls[Math.floor(Math.random()*flagurls.length)]+'.png")';
  var randomize2 = randomize;

  while (randomize2 === randomize ) {
    randomize2 = 'url("http://static.tumblr.com/zicio7x/'+flagurls[Math.floor(Math.random()*flagurls.length)]+'.png")';
  }

  document.getElementById("th1").style.backgroundImage = randomize;
  document.getElementById("th2").style.backgroundImage = randomize2;
}
```

[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/BloodyKnuckles/qr0sdku3/)